# What the purpose of setGroup() in Notification.Builder?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a some troubles with understanding of goal of [`setGroup()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String)) method.

As docs said :

> ...Grouped notifications may display in a cluster or stack on devices which support such rendering....

Here it is the first question :

#### What it is this rendering? What's so special about it?!

I create a method which show a custom text message :

```
    public static void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        notificationMessages.add(message);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentInfo("" + (notificationMessages.size()))
                /*.setGroup(++i + "")*/;

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        for (int i = 0; i < notificationMessages.size(); i++) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(notificationMessages.get(i));
        }

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

and play with `notificationID`, `setGroup` and `setGroupSummary` methods.

```
    public static void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        notificationMessages.add(message);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
//                .setGroupSummary(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentInfo("" + (notificationMessages.size()))
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY);

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        for (int i = 0; i < notificationMessages.size(); i++) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(notificationMessages.get(i));
        }

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(3), notification);
    }
```

But, no visual changes
comes if I commented lines or not. So here is a stuck for me in understanding of purpose of this method.

Comment: If you send 3 notifications with different groupId, they will be displayed as 3 different notifications. If they have the same groupId and the device supports such display, they will be displayed as a stack of notifications instead

Comment: @Blackbelt if I change the `notificationID` to different number I have separate notification. And doesn't matter if pointed group_key or not.

Comment: That's for Android N only. What device are you using?

Comment: @Budius 5.0 lolipop. Nexus 5X

Comment: @NicolasSimon no that's not a true. If I change the notificationID to different number I will have three separated notifications, but they do not collapse in one group. (I say about visual effect).

Comment: @ssh so that's your answer. That's why you won't see the difference. This blog post shows some of it: https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92#.r15105kn3

Comment: @Budius but this post is related to N version. Not about earlier. I have on NexusX 5.0 installed version, not latest.

Comment: Iv'e added as an answer properly explaining it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the official docs:

http://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-updates.html

> Android N also allows you to bundle similar notifications to appear as a single notification. To make this possible, Android N uses the existing NotificationCompat.Builder.setGroup() method. Users can expand each of the notifications, and perform actions such as reply and dismiss on each of the notifications, individually from the notification shade.

Meaning the `setGroup` will only make a difference if the device supports it.

Devices that support it are:

- Android Wear devices. when showing remote notifications, you can group together them
- Android N. Devices running the Android N developer preview (or in the future the official N release), will show a group of notifications together

The following blog post shows how those work on Android N: https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92

bellow is a render of that a group looks like:

[image]

That means that `setGroup` will make no difference on devices running anything bellow API23, that includes, Marshamallow, Lollipop, KitKat, etc.

Comment: I followed the same tutorial, why the first notification is not visible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097442/notification-with-setgroupsummarytrue-is-not-visible-in-android-n

Comment: "That means that setGroup will make no difference on devices running anything bellow API23, that includes, Marshamallow, Lollipop, KitKat, etc." On 4.4.2 the notification is not shown at all if setGroup is called. Just wanted to point that out so other people don't waste time debugging.

Comment: this linked example is incorrect. it does `.setGroupSummary(true)` on **all** of the notifications, it should be done exactly once, on the first, which is the pull-down leader

Answer (score 0):

`setGroupSummary`is there to support grouped notifications on devices before Nougat. It replaces the single notifications with 1 summary notification.
On Nougat+ the system creates a normal group, which is *not* your notification with `setGroupSummary(true)`