# Behaviour of grouped notification on Android 7

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

I create several notifications like this:

```
public class NotificationCreator {
    Context context;
    int c = 0;

    public NotificationCreator(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    void create() {

        String text = "" + c  + " " + new Date().toGMTString();

        // Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.KEY, text);
        Intent[] intents = new Intent[1];
        intents[0] = intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
                context,
                c,
                intents,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // Build notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
        builder.setContentTitle("Test");
        builder.setContentText(text);
//        builder.setGroup("");
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();

        // Send notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(c, notification);

        c++;
    }
}
```

The outcome on Android 7 is:

[image]

The system has grouped all notifications.

When I set explicitly on the builder:

```
 builder.setGroup("myGroup");
```

the outcome is:

[image]

The notifications are **not** grouped, but all shown individually, **despite** all having the same group key.

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. In the first case (grouped), can I determine what happens when the user clicks on the grouped notification? The individual intents seem to be ignored and just the app opened.

Comment: Have you tried adding `setGroupSummary(true)` to the builder when you add the group? Like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114135/2910520. Btw this is the correct behaviour, not grouped notifications from the same app stack tocketer, while the grouped ones can be expanded or shrinked, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37163589/2910520) you can find a GIF

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: Same issue, also tries setGroupSummary(true) for every notification, still same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem and figured it out by using a "Summary notification". Basically, you create one regular notification with the desired group and the "Summary notification" with the same group and `setGroupSummary(true)`.

More here https://blog.stylingandroid.com/nougat-bundled-notifications/